# installing pyqt 4 - not 5 via brew

Tags: pyqt, homebrew

I'm having issues with pyqt, so I thought I'd remove it and re-install it via `brew`.

However, `brew` insists on installing pyqt5. Is there a way to force `brew` to install pyqt4?

Comment: Looks like that's not available as Formula anymore - note that Qt4 is unmaintained since December 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Installing via MacPorts worked a treat!